# What is the flash.ctp layout for?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

What is the purpose of `Layouts/flash.ctp` which comes packaged with CakePHP by default?

It's not very pretty and I'm wondering if I can delete it as part of some clean-up I'm doing. Is it related to Session flash messages, and is it used automatically or is it a file that is provided just in case you want to use it?

Comment: As a sidenote (I think with Alex's answer is enough), I've deleted `flash.ctp` and `ajax.ctp` (rather work with ajax returning the info directly from the action), and nothing has explode and I hope no kitties have died, so I think you're safe cleaning that up.

Comment: It's for the redirect flash stuff which is deprecated anyway. So yeah, if you are not using that functionality, you can safely remove those layout files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is used for session flash messages and it is not used automatically, you have to call it manually from a controller or view.

It's not meant to be pretty :) You can style it the way you want anyway. It is just a nice way of notifying the end-user on an action.

See [Creating notification messages](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#creating-notification-messages) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It is the base layout for flash messages. The flash messages are mostly used when form is submitted to show errors and success messages and you can also separate the error layout and success flash layouts.